# how can we integrate meteor application to simple web application runs on application server?

Tags: meteor

Is there any integration meteor application with application server.
I want to create a chat client which should be integrated with my web application, i have seen meteor example and i want to explore the possibility for my requirement.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use meteor for your web application or you could put the meteor chat application in an `iframe` on your web application.

It would be difficult to actually integrate your current web application into a seperate meteor instance because meteor includes its own webserver and the meteor code can't run on what your application server's stack might be (IIS/Apache,Thin,etc). You would have to look at a way of having meteor run on its own and then integrating this into your webpage with html/javascript

If you don't have a chat application on meteor yet, there's a very good example at:

https://github.com/AVGP/meteor.js-chat-example